# What type of Authentication we should use inside our DocuSign API integration

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a developer account to test our integration with DocuSign API, but i am not sure which authentication option i need to use inside the below screen:-

[image]

now in our case we are building a registration system, with the following main requirments:-

- We will upload a contract inside DocuSign and specify that users need to sign the contract.
- inside our application, if the user complete the registration >> to inform docuSign to send the user an email to Sign the contract
- We want the same contract inside DocuSign to be sent to multiple users, and each user will Sign his own contract.

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use could this point you in the right direction? My opinion would be authorization code over implicit, however that's only my opinion.

Comment: @Isolated i thought JWT will be the best option for our case, since we are doing system integration...

Comment: JWT is the token you receive from OAuth2, its just a format Json Web Token, you'll receive a token from OAuth2 in JWT (most likely), so it's a matter of deciding which flow, how do your users usually login to your system? I mention OAuth2 as that's what docusign offer. It was also depend on how deeply you integrate Docusign

Comment: @Isolated we do not have a registration with our system, it is available to public users...

Comment: is the question here which should I use, implicit or authorization code?

Comment: @Isolated as per the documentation here https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication there are 3 types on authentication .. so i am asking which one best suite my case... i did many integration with external systems, where usually we an api key which i send with our api calls... not sure why DocuSign authentication is somehow complicated .. or i am missing something?

Comment: You're correct, it's more complicated, it uses OAuth2.0 to provide authentication (instead of an API key), there's a good answer below explaining that, also the link I originally posted may help, you use some form of credential to retrieve the JWT (which is how you make requests), instead of appending an API key `?apiKey=`.  Also keep in mind, OAuth2 isn't unique to DocuSign.

Comment: @Isolated yes i know OAuth2.0 is a standard for api authentication.. but still i can not get my mind on which option is more suitable for our case..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213649/discussion-between-isolated-and-test-test).

Answer (score 1):

This [guide would](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication) help you learn all about authentication and which of the various options you should choose and how to set it up in DocuSign Admin.

the simple summary is this:

- If each user of your integration will use a single system account to log in, you should use JWT Grant. Note that, when using JWT Grant to obtain an access token, you can still use elements of the other grants to obtain consent.
- If your integration uses a browser or client to make requests to a web server, it can use Authorization Code Grant.
- If your integration will not use a single system account to log in and does not use a browser or client to make requests to a web server, it must use Implicit Grant.

Comment: thanks i already read these.... now in our case we are building a registration system so anonymous users access the system (without the need to login), and as a last step of the registration we need to send them an email to sign the document inside DocuSign.. so this is the main process needed for the integration between our system and DocuSign,.. so my question is which authentication best suites our case?

Comment: I would consider JWT as you're going to impersonate a single user to make all the API calls. All the envelopes would be sent by that one user that you set up.

Comment: Let me know if I can help further. If you're good - please mark this as answered. thanks!

Comment: ok thanks , but inside the screen i attached there is no option to set JWT...

Comment: you are correct, you don't set it from there, you use it to obtain a token differently. 
From admin you'll need your userId (GUID) and the private RSA Key, which you can set in there.

Comment: which code lang would you use? I can point you to some examples...

Comment: appreciate your help, i am using C# inside asp.net mvc core lang

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp that is a good place to start. this supports JWT as well as Auth Code Grant. Just update the information in the appsettings file and see if you can get it running.

Comment: to be honest those examples makes the whole story even worst for me... i can not understand from where i need to start

Comment: Well, there are 2 approaches to where to start:
1. You start with auth, that's what you suggested you wanted to do.
2. You ignore auth, you start with the API, you use the token generator and just try it out. 
Since you asked to start with auth, I pointed you to the full example. I would try to clone the code and follow the instructions. It's not that hard.

Comment: @ Inbar Gazit so now if we return back to my screen shot, is there any thing i still need to do to configure JWT? or i should be fine for the first step?

Comment: you need to generate an RSA Key-pair and keep the private key handy. You will not be able to get it again after you generated it.